# Minimum value of a continuous function, only defined for positive x

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Hi I'm studying an analysis course and i have encountered the following question regarding continuity. I need to say if they're true or false.
$f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are both continuous and $f(x)$,$g(x)>0$ for all x. Is it true in either case that there exists a $c>0$ such that $f(x) \geq c$ and $g(x)\geq c$ for all x?

For f, i thought this to be untrue, and thought of a counterexample of $f(x)=e^{-x}$ as this goes arbitrarily close to 0 as x goes to infinity, so there would exist no c. I'm not sure about the continuity of the function though

The second one has stumped me a little, i know that if f os continuous on a closed and bounded interval then f is bounded on this interval, and also by the extreme value theorem is will attain its max and min on this interval. Is this enough to say that no such c exists?

Answer (score 0):

The extreme value theorem will tell you that such a $c$ must exist for $g$. Since $[0,1]$ is closed and bounded, $g$ must have a minimum value $c$ on $[0,1]$. But $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, therefore $c > 0$.

Also $f(x) = e^{-x}$ is continuous, so you're good on that counterexample.

Comment: Thanks :) I knew what i had to use just couldn't make the final conclusion

Answer (score 0):

For the function $f$, you are right.

For $g$, the result comes from this theorem:

> Let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $X$ is compact, then $f(X)$ is also compact.

Therefore, $g([0,1])$ has a minimum and it is greater than 0.

Comment: Thank you :), does compact mean closed and bounded?

Comment: a set if compact if and only if it's closed and bounded by the Heine-Borel Theorem.